# Change color of multiple separated lines of text in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I want to change the color of multiple lines of text in Wordpress.

The lines are separated like this:

Line 1 (change to green)

some other lines

Line 2 (change to green)

some other lines

Line 3 (green)

I have used CTRL and selected all the lines but when I change the color it deselects all lines except for the last one?

I would also like to insert multiple horizontal rules at different points on a page without doing them one by one.

I think the text editor is defected if it won't allow a simple ctrl and select multiple items?

Comment: Done, I keep forgetting how to use this site. As I don't be here often.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the Wordpress Visual Editor is that it was built for the lowest common denominator of users in mind. Basically, it's only useful for people with little to no experience in HTML and CSS.

Most of the time, the Visual Editor's output will either be just plain messy - or wrong - for developers to use it in a clean and concise way.

Your question has more to do with the usability of the Wordpress Visual Editor rather than HOW to use it. What I would suggest if you are not comfortable with editing your content using the HTML View (which can allow you to format your content on a much more granular level) is to copy all of your content into a Text Editor like Microsoft Word, making the changes you want, and then pasting everything back into the Editor.

It actually does fairly well using that method.

While Wordpress does the job in making things as easy as possible for the less technologically adept users, it is not foolproof. If you feel that its usability is flawed on a very fundamental level, my suggestion would be to contact the Wordpress Development team in the Wordpress forums.

Good luck.

http://wordpress.org/support/